# How to explode numbers separated by comma and bring the separated number to the next row using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame where each restaurant ID has multiple phone numbers. I would like to get explode phone numbers by comma and get the separated phone number to the next row by duplicating the restaurant ID. The original dataframe looks like this.

[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPDkA.png)

I want the output to be like this:

[Output of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0VGU.png)

Comment: Could you please share the code what you have tried so far? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `split` the phone column by commas and then use de `explode` function.

```
df['phones'] = df['phones'].str.split(',')

df.explode('phones')
```

**PS**: I can't print the results because you use images to show your data =/